# linear mixed effects models - overfit: how to calculate predictive R squared

Tags: r, mixed-model, r-squared

I am using R to build the random structure of my model but I am ending up with a very complex model. Currently looks like this:

```
Model <- lmer(x ~ y * z * d * k + (1 + y * z + d | subject), 
              data = Data, 
              REML = FALSE, 
              control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
                        optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

I would like to know if I am simply overfitting. How can I get a predictive R-squared for linear mixed effects models? Is there a way to calculate these values?

I am aware of the package MuMIn for getting Rsquared values but I am concerned with overfitting, so I wanted to see if the degrees of freedom are biasing too much the AIC and p-values when comparing the models using anova.

Comment: R-squared won't help you. You need either CV or a test set.

Comment: I want the predictive R-squared, not the R-squared as I know the R-squared increases with the number of predictors. Do you think AIC would be enough?

Comment: You just need to decide what criterion you want to use.  AIC or BIC or AICc are fine to use as model selection criteria.  There's also adjusted r-squared.  There are also techniques like LASSO and ridge regression.  They don't all agree, so you have to decide what criterion is important for your purposes.

Comment: @CatM I don't know how the predictive R-squared is estimated, but given that mixed models already have problems estimating the normal / adjusted R-squared, this may be a hard task. I would use a more common approach, such as AIC or a test set predictions.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question...  The approach for calculating predictive r-square for linear models is given at [this rpubs page](https://rpubs.com/RatherBit/102428).  It won't work directly for mixed models.  There is an [influence function in the `car` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-2/topics/influence.mixed.models)  for mixed models, but I couldn't figure out how to adapt this to the purpose....  If I understand predictive r-squared, probably the most fruitful approach would be to write a function that removes data observation by observation and sees how well the model predicts the dropped observation.  I didn't see anything that addresses how this would be done specifically.

Comment: Yes, but the removal should probably be group-by-group rather than observation-by-observation (and good luck with crossed random effects)